# Including -lib command line parameters in ant build.xml

Tags: ant, command-line-arguments

I have a build script that requires the -lib command line switch like so:

ant *-lib lib/jsch-20101122.jar*  ....

This works fine, but I'd like to include that command line argument as part of my build.xml file and make my build cleaner.

I'd prefer not to include this jar in my ANT_HOME/bin directory.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: could you show the target you need the lib for? Usually you can include libs directly for most tasks.

Comment: looking for same thing ? Any success?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you want to use the scp-task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html)

The official doc (http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks) for optional Tasks offers no real alternative (you may want to look at the CLASSPATH alternative, though).

The scp-task does not seem to have a classpath setting.